# Sending temperature sensor's data to Kaa-IoT platform via 6LoWPAN

Tags: smart-home, raspberry-pi, arduino, system-architecture, 6lowpan

I want to set up some sensors in different places, which are wire connected to my development board, Raspberry PI or Arduino.

I'm going to send the data wirelessly but without using WiFi protocol, The best options for low range IoT projects are 6LoWPAN and ZigBee protocols. My next target would be using Kaa-IoT Platform as a Cloud Service, which makes my data available regardless of where I am.

I want to implement a circuit like [Raspberry Pi Temperature Sensor: Build a DS18B20 Circuit](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-temperature-sensor/).

Which architecture is proper for this project?
Right now I don't know if there is a way to use 6LoWPAN with Raspberry PI. (Although I'm aware of this [link](http://openlabs.co/store/Raspberry-Pi-802.15.4-radio))

I read some notes about installing RIOT operating system on Arduino board, which supports the 6LoWPAN protocol. (But still, don't know how to set it up and which extra modules I need to attach to Arduino board)

For the conclusion, I need to collect sensors information, send them via the 6LoWPAN protocol to the proper modem, which connects me to the internet and Kaa-IoT platform, at the end I'm going to write an Android app which is a link to my Kaa account.

I don't know which hardware is suitable for this IoT project...